# How to make static div take up half of the page with 100% height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a static div stay on 50% of the left side of the screen and function as the navigation. The content will be on the right side and is scrollable. An example would be this site http://minusfirm.com/
Can anyone help me crack this nut? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, first I will assume you want this in pure CSS so here I will give  you the code. This code will have the floats react to different screen sizes.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#mainNavigation {
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  width: 50%;
}
#mainNavigation li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 35%;
}
#otherContent {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  padding-left: 21%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainNavigation">
  <h1>Heading, Image, or Title</h1>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="otherContent">
  <h2>All of this content is assumed</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
    <br />adipiscing elit. Vivamus ante magna, malesuada
    <br />nec ligula eget, hendrerit porttitor mauris.
    <br />Praesent in.
</div>
```

With a bit of tweaking with media queries this code will be about as mobile as the example Minus Firm. The reason I add the padding properties seperately is to help visualize the code.

Comment: Today I feel like pasta

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
<div style="width: 50%;">
   <div style="float:left; width: 50%">
   Navigation
   </div>
   <div style="float:right;">
   Other Stuff
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the width of your two divs at 50% `width: 50%;`
and make one of your position fixed     `position: fixed;`

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav" class="centertext">
  right side
</div>
<div id="content">
  left side
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    width: 50%;
    position: fixed;
   float: left;

    background: #01ffA0;
}
#content {  
  float:right;
  width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background: #0130A0;
}
```

check this codepen for more details [Link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yebjoJ)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it's a combo of two different CSS settings:

1. The navigation section on the left has a position of fixed (and definitions of where in the display it is "fixed" to), and is set to 100% height and 50% width.
2. The content section on the right is set to float to the right (literally "float: right;" in the CSS), and the width is set to take up the remaining 50%.

The following HTML is a made-up example, based on the site you linked to.  Just copy the html, paste it into a text editor, and save the file as "largenav.html" or some other html file. Then open it in a browser.

```
        <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                #nav {
                    width:50%;
                    height:100%;
                    position: fixed;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    background: #FF8833;
                }

                #content {
                    width: 50%;
                    float: right;
                    background: #3388FF;
                }
                div.scrollsection {
                    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
                    display: block;
                    height:  1000px;
                    background: #888888;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li>First Nav</li>
                    <li>Second Nav</li>
                    <li>etc.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="content">
                <div class="scrollsection">First chunk of scroll content</div>
                <div class="scrollsection">Second chunk of scroll content</div>
                <div class="scrollsection">Third chunk of scroll content</div>
                <div class="scrollsection">[You get the idea...]</div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I would also recommend getting familiar with the developer tools in your favorite browser (personally, I use Google Chrome for all initial development, just because of the dev tools.  However, I don't want to start a flame war--FireFox has some good built in tools and excellent addons that make life wonderful, and I haven't used MS Edge, but IE developer tools were getting better over time.)